# Flex BitmapImage Wont Load From URL

Tags: apache-flex, url, bitmap, bitmapimage

i am making a news slider that loads content from a php script. The problem is when i put the url into the source of the BitmapImage for the thumbnail, the image never loads:

```
var newsItemThumb:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        newsItemThumb.source = XMLReader.newsItem[i].thumb;
                        newsItemThumb.fillMode = "stretch";
                        newsItemThumb.width = 100;
                        newsItemThumb.height = 100;

                        // add the thumb to news
                        newsItem.addElement(newsItemThumb);
```

Comment: i actually worked around it, but unsure why it happened. I set the value of the XMLReader.newsItem[i].thumb to a string variable and it works that way...very odd!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above, maybe the value of the code below

```
XMLReader.newsItem[i].thumb;
```

is empty or `null`. Can you try debug your code and lets see what's the current value of it?

Comment: i actually worked around it, but unsure why it happened. I set the value of the XMLReader.newsItem[i].thumb to a string variable and it works that way...very odd!

Comment: Cool. It really seems that the value XMLReader.newsItem[i].thumb is empty. :)